# Form submitted twice using submit() on keyup

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, jquery-events, double-submit-problem

I had a jQuery / HTML code similar to this:

```
<form action="/SomeAction" method="post">
  <input id="my-textbox" type="text" placeholder="Write something and press enter to continue..." />
</form>

<script type="text/javascript">
 $(function() {
     $('#my-textbox').keyup(function(e) {
        var $textbox = $(this);
        if ($textbox.val().length > 0 && e.keyCode == 13) {
           $textbox.parent('form').submit();
        }
     });
 });
</script>
```

The purpose was to automatically submit the form when the user pressed the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key. I regularly use Firefox so everything was OK for me until I tested in Google Chrome and Internet Explorer.

When I pressed the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key in the later browsers, sometimes I would get the form submitted twice. This was easy to notice because I would get duplicate entries in my DB and I'd see two `POST`s using Fiddler.

After some testing, I found out that my problem was the jQuery code, since the textbox would submit automatically on enter without it, and using this code would produce a second `POST` in some browsers.

**My questions are:**

Why don't browsers smartly prevent the second form post (like Firefox did in my testing)?

Should I expect this behavior in all major browsers in all platforms?

Is there a way to improve this code so I perform the submit using JavaScript, but don't get the form submitted twice?

Comment: try blocking the default event.

Comment: You are having the form submitted on keyup. You are requesting the JavaScript submit the form each time there is a keyup event in the text field. You're getting exactly what you are asking for.

Comment: I'm not a jquery expert but I would hook your code to the submit event in the form (or hook a function on it blocking it's default behaviour)

Comment: @EvikJames Not true. He is only submitting the form if the field isn't empty and the key pressed is the enter key. Look closer.

Comment: How do I submit the form without using the keyboard? For example, click to get focus, speech recognition to enter text and... what?

Comment: @EvikJames the form is only submitted when e.keyCode == 13 (enter) is pressed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Why don't browsers smartly prevent the second form post (like Firefox did in my testing)?

That is the default behavior. What if you didn't have your script and the default behavior was such that the form wouldn't POST on <kbd>enter</kbd>.

> Should I expect this behavior in all major browsers in all platforms?

Yes

> Is there a way to improve this code so I perform the submit using JavaScript, but don't get the form submitted twice?

Use a global `mutex` variable and set it once the form POSTs - checking it on subsequent POSTs to validate. Or, return false from the `keyup` handler and stop the event propagation.

Answer (score 5):

Some browsers will interpret an input button as a submit if there is only one button in the form. Just `return false` in your function to prevent the default behavior from submitting the form.

```
if ($textbox.val().length > 0 && e.keyCode == 13) {
    $textbox.parent('form').submit();
    return false;
}
```

Comment: He's doing this in keyup, so it's too late to prevent default. See @Sheikh's example.

Comment: not true. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2037910/possible-to-prevent-enter-from-submitting-a-form-in-javascript-from-certain-inpu

Comment: @Hexxagonal im only seeing one post-back in both Chrome18 and IE8 regardless, so i am not able to validate your test.

Answer (score 2):

Your form is being submitted right after the enter has been pressed (on keydown and before keyup fires) so you can do

```
$(function() {
    $('#my-textbox').keydown(function(e){
        if(e.keyCode==13) e.preventDefault();
    }); 

    $('#my-textbox').keyup(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var $textbox = $(this);
        if($textbox.val().length > 0 && e.keyCode == 13) {
           $textbox.parent('form').submit();
        }
     });
 });​
```

[**A simple test.**](http://jsfiddle.net/u7KVj/)

Answer (score 1):

Add boolean variable that would be set to true after first submit and use that variable in your if condition. This would prevent accidental double click.

You should also prevent double submit in the application backend (many web frameworks have built-in mechanism for doing this, it easy to come up with custom solution as well).

Comment: I tried, but I got two form posts anyway: one from my code and one from the browser's default event.